# compare from different table inside case statement

Tags: sql

I am struggling with a use case and any help is appreciated.
I need to do through SQL and no other programming language.Use case is below explained.
I have two table :

TABLE 1:

```
name code_1 code_2
abc  234    
abc  123   234
xyz        345
```

TABLE 2:

```
name code rank
abc 234   1
abc 456   2
xyz 345   1
xyz 678   2
```

So i have two table and i need to check whether the population in the TABLE 1 column code_1 and code_2 is correct or not.

table1 has three coloumns with first column as name ,second column having default value and third column name is  derived using the table 2.

table 2 is majorly a look up table which has three column namely name same as above table ,second column is code and third column is rank.

I need to create a query to check whether the population made in table 1 is correct or not.

Rules for population:

1. if for a name, code 1 in table 1 is null,take rank 1 from look up table(table2 )for that name in the code 2 column.
2. if for a name code 1 is populated and is not in the list of code as per table 2 for that name then populate rank 1 from table 2 in code 2 column.
3. if code 1 is correct then leave it as it is and nothing should go to code 2 in table 1.

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: It would help to explain what you want if you would add some expected results based on that sample data. Also, what kind of database do you need this for? And what have you tried?

Comment: I need to find out  whether the population is correct or not in the code 2 coloumn in tabel1. so for first row where name is abc and for abc in the table 2 we have 234 so it is correct.but for abc 123 in code 1 (2nd row) is not correct as per table 2.so that is fail.Tabe2 is the look up which we need to refer. need to count how many are fail.

Comment: i guess we need to use different case structures but not sure how to join other table inside a case statement.also not necessarily there will be only two codes.there could be multiple codes for a name.

Answer (score 0):

I would summarize the second table and do a comparison.  Something like this:

```
select name,
       (case when count(*) = 1 and max(which) = 1 then 'Only in table1'
             when count(*) = 1 and max(which) = 2 then 'Only in table2'
             when (max(code_1_1) = max(code_1_2) or max(code_1_1) is null and max(code_1_2) is null) and
                  (max(code_2_1) = max(code_2_2) or max(code_2_1) is null and max(code_2_2) is null)
            then 'Same'
             else 'Different'
        end) as which,
       max(code_1_1), max(code_1_2), max(code_2_1), max(code_2_2)
from ((select name, code_1_1, code2_2, null as code_1_2, null as code_2_2, 1 as which
       from table1
      ) union all
      (select name, null, null, max(case when rank = 1 then code end), max(case when rank = 2 then code end), 2
       from table2
       group by name
      )
     ) tt
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check it with your data but something like this should do:

```
update Table1 
set code_2=t2.Code
from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2
on  t1.name=t2.name and t2.rank=1
where t1.Code_1 is null

update Table1 
set code_2=t2.Code
from Table1 t1 inner join Table2 t2
on  t1.name=t2.name and t2.rank=1
where t1.Code_1 is not null 
    and t1.Code_1 not in 
    (select  Code from Table2)
```